# Limit List's objects amount - SwiftUi

Tags: swift, list, core-data, swiftui, apple-watch

My WatchOS app running on Core Data. There are 2 Views there:

1. FirstView - a view with a button to Add a new Goal and a List of added Goals.
2. AddGoalView - appears after pressing Add new Goal.

I also added `List` as I want to use `.onDelete` in my App.

I am trying to limit the user in creation infinite number of Goals. I'd like to give an opportunity of adding maximum 10 Goals, then the AddGoal button becomes disabled. Do you have any suggestions how I can do that?

First View Code:

```
struct FirstView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest (
    entity:NewGoal.entity(),
       sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NewGoal.dateAdded, ascending: false)],
        animation: .easeInOut )

var results:FetchedResults<NewGoal>
var body: some View {
        VStack{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            NavigationLink(
                    destination: AddGoalView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Set Money Goal")})
                        Text("10/10")

             VStack(alignment: .leading){
                List{
                ForEach(results){ item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: TABmodule(goalItem: item, GTitle: item.goalTitle ?? "", Sum: item.neededSum, summarize: item.yourSum),
                            label: {
                                HStack{
                                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing:0){
                                            Text(String(item.indDatenum))
                                            Text(item.pickedValueDateS ?? "")
                                        }

                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(item.goalTitle ?? "")
          
                                    HStack(spacing: 0){
                                        Text("$\(item.yourSum, specifier: "%.f")")
                                        Text("/ $\(item.neededSum, specifier: "%.f")")
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                    }).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9))
                    
                } .onDelete(perform: deleteGoal2)
                }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())

                }
            }
        }
    }
func deleteGoal2(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
        let item = results[index]
        context.delete(item)
    }
    do{
        try context.save()
    }catch let err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
}
}
```

AddGoal func on the AddGoalView:

```
    private func addGoal(){
    
    if index == 0 {
        pickedValueDateS = "W"
        pickedValueDateN = 7 * indexnum
        pickedValueDateN1 = 7 * indexnum
        } else if index == 1{
            pickedValueDateS = "M"
            pickedValueDateN = 30 * indexnum
            pickedValueDateN1 = 30 * indexnum
        } else if index == 2{
            pickedValueDateS = "Y"
            pickedValueDateN = 365 * indexnum
            pickedValueDateN1 = 365 * indexnum
    } else {
        pickedValueDateS = "N/A"
        pickedValueDateN = 1
    }
    let goal = NewGoal(context: context)
    goal.goalTitle = goalTitle
    goal.dateAdded = Date()
    goal.neededSum = neededSum
    goal.pickedValueDateS = pickedValueDateS
    goal.allNewSum = allNewSum
    goal.pickedValueDateN = Int64(pickedValueDateN)////ALL DAYS
    goal.pickedValueDateN1 = Int64(pickedValueDateN1)////MINUS DAYS
    goal.dayChange = Int64(daychange)
    goal.indDate = Int64(index)
    goal.indDatenum = Int64(indexnum)
    
    
    do{
        try context.save()
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }catch let err{
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to any `View` you want disabled like the `NavigationLink` so the user can't go to that `View`

```
.disabled(results.count >= 10)
```